# Console.log always returns undefined in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just encountered this weird problem. I don't remember I have it before but it has been quite a while since last time I develop any Chrome stuff.

The picture below pretty much speaks it by itself:

[image]

Why does Chrome console constantly return undefined for `console.log` command? Any `console.log` used in js scripts also return the same.

---

Update

`console.log.toString()` returns `"function log() { [native code] }"`

Comment: What does console.log.toString() show?

Comment: This the default behavior don't worry.

Comment: because console.log does not return anything! That means it returns undefined.

Comment: @epascarello why are you so impatient? can't you look at the screenshot and see the real problem?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Explain how it is a dupe? `var a = 1;` produces undefined without the console line.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir um...... wrong question?

Comment: @epascarello the author incorrectly wrote "returned undefined" because of poor knowledge of english but if you look at the screenshot, you can see `console.log` *prints* incorrectly

Comment: Actually it never prints anything. Maybe some non-standard environment.

Comment: My guess, something overwritten console.log(), but impossible to tell with what is provided. What does `console.log.toString()` return? My guess it is not `"function log() { [native code] }"` or you filtering out logs.

Comment: @epascarello, indeed, I should have used the word `prints` and it turns out it's a duplication of the question you linked.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Are you filtering the messages by chance? Look in the upper right corner of the console to see if it says “1 hidden”.

[image: Screenshot of devtools, "Hide all / 6 hidden" emphasized]